# How does one show that $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\over k+1}\cdot{ \lceil \log_2(k) \rceil}=1-2\gamma?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions, euler-mascheroni-constant

Consider

> $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\over k+1}\cdot{  \lceil \log_2(k) \rceil}=1-2\gamma\tag1$$

How does on show that $(1)$ converges to $1-2\gamma?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given series equals
$$ \sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}+\sum_{k\geq 3}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}+\sum_{k\geq 7}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}+\ldots \tag{1}$$
or
$$ \log(2)-\frac{1}{2}+\int_{0}^{1}\left[\sum_{h\geq 2}\sum_{k\geq 2^h-1}(-x)^k\right]\,dx \tag{2}$$
hence the claim boils down to proving [Catalan's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html)$^{(*)}$
$$ \gamma=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x}\sum_{n\geq 1}x^{2^n-1}\,dx \tag{3}$$
where the RHS of $(3)$ equals
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{m\geq 0}(-1)^m x^m \sum_{n\geq 1}x^{2^n}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x}\sum_{m\geq 2} r(m) x^m\tag{4}$$
with $r(m)$ being the difference between the number of ways we may represent $m$ as $2^a+2b$ and the number of ways we may represent $m$ as $2^a+(2b+1)$ with $a\geq 1$ and $b\geq 0$.

$(*)$ The linked page shows a derivation, $(24)\to(29)$, based on Euler's series acceleration method.

Comment: Wonderfully weaved!  Never would've managed to connect all those points together.

Comment: $\texttt{Mathematica}$ yields
$$
\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{k} \over k + 1}\,
\left\lceil\log_{\mathrm{2}}\left(k\right)\right\rceil - \left(1 - 2\gamma\right) \approx 0.0361703
$$

Comment: @FelixMarin: that is a numerical issue for sure. The series is very slow-convergent and the numerical errors arising from $\lceil\log(\cdot)\rceil$ accumulate. The derivation on Wolfram speaks clear.

Comment: I just checked Wolfram. It's right. Thanks.